# Simple PHP chat quirk

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, chat

I've been working on a quick and simple jQuery/PHP chat to put in my website for the visitors to communicate. I've extimated peaks of 200 simultaneous website users (connected users) with at most 10-20 people actually chatting.

**Here's the quirk:**

As I experienced already twice (thought it seems to be rather an unlikely event more than something happening after you perform something specific) **the chat happens to load multiple messages which have already been red and display them.**

Trying to keep the chat system as simple as possibile I came up with this code:

---

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="chat">

    <ul class="chat">

        <li class="chat" >

            <h5 class="chat">Date</h5>
            <h6 class="chat">Time</h6>
            <h4 class="chat">User</h4>
            <br/>
            <q class="chat">Message</q>

        </li>

    </ul>

    <input class="chat" placeholder="write something..."/>

</div>
```

As you can see I put a placeholder *li* element for the jQuery to take and use as a snippet to create new *li* elements with the actual messages and **prepend** them inside the *ul* element.

---

**jQuery CODE:**

Sending messages:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    chatSnippet = $('ul.chat').html(); // here chatSnippet is a global variable
    $('ul.chat').html('');

    $('input.chat').change(function(event){// Send your message

    message = $(this).attr('value');

// first thing I perform an asynchronous POST to the receiving php script

    $.post(

        'php/chatRec.php',

        {

            user : currentUser,
            message: message,

        }

    );

// meanwhile I add a new li element to the chat html with the content just submitted


    date.setTime(event.timeStamp);

    hours = ''+date.getHours();

    if(hours.length < 2) hours = '0'+hours;

    minutes = ''+date.getMinutes();

    if(minutes.length < 2) minutes = '0'+minutes;

    day = ''+date.getDate();

    if(day.length < 2) day = '0'+day;

    newChatMessage = chatSnippet.replace('Date', ''+day+' '+months[date.getMonth()]);
    // here months is an array with the months names (in italian)
    newChatMessage = newChatMessage.replace('Time', ''+hours+':'+minutes);

    newChatMessage = newChatMessage.replace('User', connectedUser);

    newChatMessage = newChatMessage.replace('Message', message);

    $mess = $(newChatMessage);

    $mess.hide().prependTo('ul.chat').fadeIn(500);

    $(this).attr('value','');

});

refreshChat(''); // this function retrives new messages from the DB

// Here I perform a void refreshChat call so I'll get all the messages in the DB regardless from the currentUser (at page refresh)

});
```

Receiving messages:

```
// This code is placed outside (before) the .ready function

function refreshChat(user){// Receiving messages

$.post(

    'php/chatInv.php',

    {

        user : user,
        token: lastMessage // this variable contains the token of the last red message

    },

    function(data){

        receivedMessages = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        for(message in receivedMessages){

            message = receivedMessages[message].Message;

            date = receivedMessages[message].Day.split('-');
            time = receivedMessages[message].Time.split(':');

            newChatMessage = chatSnippet.replace('Date', ''+date[2]+' '+months[parseInt(date[1])-1]);

            newChatMessage = newChatMessage.replace('Time', ''+time[0]+':'+time[1]);

            newChatMessage = newChatMessage.replace('User', receivedMessages[message].Sender);

            newChatMessage = newChatMessage.replace('Message', message);

            $mess = $(newChatMessage);

            $mess.hide().prependTo('ul.chat').fadeIn(500);

            lastMessage = receivedMessages[messages].token;

        }

        nextRefresh = setTimeout("refreshChat('"+currentUser+"')",2000);

// When I'm done I set a timeout of 2 secs and then perform another refresh

    }

);

}
```

---

**PHP CODE:**

Receive a new message (I think the issue is in here):

```
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("chat") or die(mysql_error());

    $characters = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');

    $token = $characters[rand(0,61)].$characters[rand(0,61)].$characters[rand(0,61)].$characters[rand(0,61)].$characters[rand(0,61)];

    $all_Msgs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages ORDER BY ID");

    $prev_Msg = array('ID' => 1 , 'Sender' => $_POST['user'], 'Message' => $_POST['message'], 'Day' => date("Y-m-d"), 'Time' => date("H:i:s"), 'token' => $token);

    while($Msg = mysql_fetch_array($all_Msgs)){

        $update_success = mysql_query("UPDATE Messages SET Sender='".$prev_Msg['Sender']."', Message='".$prev_Msg['Message']."', Day='".$prev_Msg['Day']."', Time='".$prev_Msg['Time']."', token = '".$prev_Msg['token']."' WHERE ID=".$Msg['ID']);

        $prev_Msg = $Msg;

    }
```

Basically what I do here is receive the new post message, generate a token and an array element (which is itself an array) containing the new entered datas, done this I perform a seuqence of UPDATE statements on a fixed size SQL table overriding the new datas on the first record and then overriding each record with the previous one (so that the last record will be finally lost).

Sending messages:

```
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("chat") or die(mysql_error());

    $receiver = $_POST['user'];
    $token = $_POST['token'];

    $all_Msgs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages ORDER BY ID");

    $newMessages = array();

    while($Msg = mysql_fetch_array($all_Msgs)){

        if($Msg['token'] == $token) break;

        if($Msg['Sender'] != $receiver) array_unshift($newMessages,$Msg);

    }

    echo json_encode($newMessages);
```

So I send the client the JSON encode of an array of all the records in the DB inserted after the last known message and whose author was not the querying client.

---

**My suspects:**

I came to the conclusion that when the message reception (server side) is being performed there is a time span when each message is taken from the DB, if a refresh is being performed in the meanwhile the message is not found and if that message was the one we were looking for as the *last red message* then the server will just select all the messages in the table and send them back.

The result is you see a bunch of messages you already red without your messages in between (cuz they were added to the view client side and the server script doesn't send you back your own messages)

Stated that:

- I don't care if the messages aren't exactly in the actual insertion order: let's say A and B are chatting, the actual real messages order is BAB, but A may se the order ABB for his view is immediatly updated at input time (this helps me keep a 'fast-realtime' feel)
- I don't care if some message is lost (like if it falls over the fixed DB table edge before someone can read it)
- At this time I don't care much about actual efficency, speed and optimization
- I know I should probalby handle the message insertion differently adding the new record and then updating the IDs only and delete the last record out. But if possible I'd like to keep this UPDATE-only fashion.

**do you think my interpretation of the problem is right?**
If not: what would then be the cause? / how can I fix that?
If yes: how can I fix that easily?

If the actual fix is rather complex: how actually likely to happen would be this quirk in a 10-20 users chat?

Thanks

Comment: Friendly reminder to **watch out for SQL injection!** :-) Hopefully you were planning to add such safeguards after this initial prototype, but I personally would do it from the start.

Comment: sure I will, I actually had some formatting/escaping functions I just cut out the code here :D

Comment: Good to hear. Better yet, avoid the mess of escaping altogether by employing [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) using PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: @Onheiron `mysql_query` was killed off in PHP 7 so it's time to move on. I'd strongly recommend using PDO at the absolute minimum, or an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) if you're serious about doing this right. Even better, a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) will make this even easier to get right the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this when I worked on a chat code too, the solution is to store the last message ID (set as an Auto Increment field in MySQL) in a session and search the database for messages where the ID is higher than that, rather than use the time() function.

```
if (!$_SESSION['message_id']]) {
// if there isn't a message_id, select the last seven entries in the message list
    $sql = "SELECT messages.message_id, messages.message, users.username FROM (SELECT * FROM messages, users user.user_id = messages.user_id ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 7) as new_tbl ORDER BY message_id ASC";
} else {
// if there is a message_id, select the messages sent since the last entry
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT messages.message_id, messages.message, users.username FROM messages, users WHERE user.user_id = messages.user_id message_id > '%d'", $_SESSION['message_id']);
}

$data = array();
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
// build the data array from the mysql result and set the message_id session to the id of the last message
    $data[$i] = array('user' => $row['username'], 'message' => $row['message']);
    $_SESSION['message_id'] = $row['message_id'] > $_SESSION['message_id'] ? $row['message_id'] : $_SESSION['message_id'];
    $i++;
}
```

Obviously you'd need to escape the session!

If there isn't a message_id session, it loads the last 7 messages from the table (ordered descending, then orders those messages in ascending order). If there is a message_id session, it loads new messages.

In the while loop, it builds a data array (I send it to my script as JSON) and sets the message_id session as the message_id row, with a failsafe check to make sure the message_id session doesn't end up being lowered.

The SQL implies that you have a table of users with the user_id and username, and a table of messages with a user_id, message_id and message.

Comment: this is actually quite good : if I bind the search to a "greater than" instead of "equals" I'll actually be able to stop even if the last red message is not in the table somehow!

Comment: I basically encountered all the problems you are facing now and this was the only solution I came up with. I refresh the chat every 0.2 seconds and don't get duplicates.

Comment: wow this sounds good! Isn't 0.2 secs freq. high? I feared I'd encounter traffic/congeston problems so I set it at 2 secs... is there something like a maximum requests per second or some a server can handle? Thanks.

Comment: it depends on the server, but usually it goes by % of data and maximum number of processes at one time (these processes don't take very long if you index your tables properly and limit queries!), and if you're sending a request and returning no data, you're bandwidth usage will be minimal. When I say I refresh every 0.2 seconds, that's the timeout, but after doing a check it's actually every 0.4 seconds as the timeout fires when the request is completed, so the request takes 0.2 seconds too.

Comment: If dragging through four year old answers and making snarky comments is your thing, go you! I was providing an example and didn't expect the user to access the session global directly, including superfluous code to prove a point makes the answer more complicated, getting to my solution of storing the ID in a session was more relevant than showing how to escape the data, which I would expect somebody to know how to do.

Comment: I didn't realize the age of this question, it got bumped to some reason to the first MySQL page. I've retracted my comment.